# SAP NCo 3.0 SAP.Middleware.Connector missing RfcDestinationManager.TryGetDestination()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm trying to fix the SAP NCo 3.0 "destination configuration already initialized" error.

Here is my code:

```
using SAP.Middleware.Connector;
string ConnectionName = "connectionName";
        IDestinationConfiguration destinationConfig = null;

        bool destinationIsInitialised = false;

        if (!destinationIsInitialised)
        {
            destinationConfig = new SAPConfig();
            destinationConfig.GetParameters(ConnectionName);

            if (RfcDestinationManager.TryGetDestination(ConnectionName) == null)
            {
                RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(destinationConfig);
            }
        }
```

However, my SAP.Middleware.Connector doesn't have the RfcDestinationManager.TryGetDestination(). Am I missing something? Please help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#region sapnco.dll, v3.0.0.42
#endregion

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SAP.Middleware.Connector
{
    public class RfcDestinationManager
    {
        public static List<RfcDestinationMonitor> DestinationMonitors { get; 

        public static RfcDestination GetDestination(RfcConfigParameters parameters);
        public static RfcDestination GetDestination(string destinationName);
        public static void RegisterDestinationConfiguration(IDestinationConfiguration config);
        public static RfcDestination TryGetDestination(string destinationName);
        public static void UnregisterDestinationConfiguration(IDestinationConfiguration config);
        public delegate void ConfigurationChangeHandler(string destinationName, RfcConfigurationEventArgs args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi user1684650 and welcome to Stack Overflow!  While code-only answers can answer the question, we generally ask for people to also include a written English explanation of *how* or *why* the code solves the problem.  Could you do that?  (IN an edit to the answer, not a comment.)  Thanks!